# Javascript Function works on a local image but not on a taken image from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using [jQuery Zoom](https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom) to zoom images that I get from an Ajax request. So let's start with the working example. 
When I use my own image from the folder as follows it works perfectly, this means my js function to zoom it's not the problem:

```
<span class='zoom' id='idImg'>
    <img src='img/me.jpg' width='200' height='200'/>
</span>
```

And this is how I call the zoom when a user grabs the image:

```
 <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.zoom.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#idImg').zoom({ on:'grab' });
        });
    </script>
```

Now let's see when it fails, this is what I do to get image url:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "someUrl/getImages.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
            $("#idImg").html("<img src="+result["image"]+"width='200' height='200'/>")  
        },
        error: function (response) {
        console.log("error" + response)
    }
```

So the image I get from Ajax gets printed perfectly on the span with ID `IdImg` this means the Ajax request is working, the only thing that fails now is when I try to grab image it does not zoom.

Comment: try: `$("#idImg").html("<img src="+result["image"]+"width='200' height='200'/>").zoom({ on:'grab' })` my guess is the handler is being removed so you need to add it back on

Comment: The `$.fn.zoom` plugin probably doesn't work on elements added later, it just runs on what's present. There's not much you can do about that, unless the plugin has an option for it, or you modify the plugin, or just call the plugin again after the elements have loaded

Comment: Try putting `$('#idImg').zoom()` in it's own method and call it again when the image comes in through `success()`. You are trying to zoom on an image that wasn't downloaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the content of `#idImg` that `zoom()` was instantiated on no longer exists in the DOM after the AJAX request. To fix this you need to call `zoom()` again on the new content within the `success` handler:

```
success: function (result) {
  $("#idImg").html('<img src="' + result["image"] + '" width="200" height="200" />').zoom({ 
    on: 'grab' 
  });
},
```